# Convert @@IDENTITY  to uniqueidentifier in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table with auto generate id(identity column) 
I take that value using @@identity.How can convert this to unique identifier?

```
select @@IDENTITY 
set @Id = CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, @@IDENTITY )
```

Comment: That conversion makes no sense. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Not related to your question, but `scope_identity()` is almost always a better choice than `@@identity`. `@@identity` gives the last identity for a given session, whereas `scope_identity()` gives the last identity in current session & scope. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server `uniqueidentifier` type is not a 'unique identifier'. Is a [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a 16 byte [RPC UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) type of value. Converting a SQL Server `uniqueidentifier` to and from `int` makes no sense.

Comment: I agree entirely - roughly equivalent to turning lead into gold. ;)

Comment: Actually, there is a sort of sense to it... I'm working on a database where I need a deterministic algorithm to map an INT value to a UUID. It ought to be possible to fill the lower bits of the field with an integer value, then use some sort of mask for the upper bits. However, it seems to make more sense to just create a list of UUID's and index them.

Answer (score 0):

`@@IDENTITY` returns the last identity in the current session (from an `INSERT`, `SELECT INTO`, or `bulk copy` statement).

You cant have a uniqueidentifier column set as an identity column - this is not supported in SQL Server. Therefor your question makes no sense unless your actually trying to convert an INT identity to some kind of hash?

The most you could do is take `@@IDENTITY` from an insert (of lets say an integer ID column with `IsIdentity` set to true) then hash it - NOTE: **the resulting hash is NOT a GUID**:

```
  INSERT    INTO [Test].[dbo].[tbl_uqTest]
            ( Test )
  VALUES    ( 'x' )
  SELECT    CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), @@IDENTITY)), 2)
```

I will say however - I really cant think of a good reason to do this!